# why can't use DataFrame[DataFrame.ColumnA == somevalue] after the use of DataFrame.rename()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have data as shown below,

```
In [20]: test_data
Out[22]: 
                    ut  first_name_ini
0  WOS:000386321800001     Enriquez, F
1  WOS:000386321800001      Troyano, J
2  WOS:000386321800001  Lopez-Solaz, T
3  WOS:000386321800002    da Rochaa, S
4  WOS:000386321800002  Braz Junior, G
```

Then count the elements in "`first_name_ini`" column, and get a DataFrame(group_index) with two columns, "`index`" and "`irst_name_ini`"

```
In [23]: test_data.first_name_ini.value_counts().reset_index()
Out[23]: 
            index  first_name_ini
0      Troyano, J               1
1  Braz Junior, G               1
2    da Rochaa, S               1
3  Lopez-Solaz, T               1
4     Enriquez, F               1
```

after renaming the columns' names, errors were raised when filtering the data:

```
group_index = test_data.first_name_ini.value_counts().reset_index() 
group_index.rename(columns={'index':'name','first_name_ini':'count'}, inplace=True)
```

```
In [24]: group_index[group_index.count == 50]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3077             try:
-> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: False

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-f9c9f110b694> in <module>()
----> 1 group_index[group_index.count == 50]

d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2686             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2687         else:
-> 2688             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2689 
   2690     def _getitem_column(self, key):

d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2693         # get column
   2694         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2695             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2696 
   2697         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   2487         res = cache.get(item)
   2488         if res is None:
-> 2489             values = self._data.get(item)
   2490             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   2491             cache[item] = res

d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   4113 
   4114             if not isna(item):
-> 4115                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   4116             else:
   4117                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]

d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3079             except KeyError:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   3081 
   3082         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: False
```

but when change to the code below, it works

```
In [25]: group_index[group_index['count'] == 50]
Out[25]: 
                 name  count
2723           Dey, N     50
2724           Tan, Q     50
2725        Bazzan, A     50
2726           Fan, K     50
2727         Botti, V     50
2728      Atkinson, K     50
```

So what's the difference between `DataFrame[DataFrame.ColumnA == somevalue]` and `DataFrame[DataFrame['ColumnA'] == somevalue]`, as here `group_index[group_index['count'] == 50]` to `group_index[group_index.count == 50]`, and why error raised after the `DataFrame.rename()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because the column `count` you are referring to conflicted with the [pandas.DataFrame.count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) method, so this attribute-style access is not possible. It is  encouraged to always use explicit dictionary-style `group_index['count'] == 50` when filtering.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between `group_index.count` and `group_index['count']` is that the first is called as an attribute of the object whilst the second is an index of the object. If the count column did not exist beforehand, you cannot call it as an attribute since that attribute has not be set and therefore python wouldn't know what you're referring to. However, if you use indexing to set it to something (such as the case of using `group_index['count']`), pandas would create the new attribute under the hood and set it to your value when you use `group_index['count']` akin to what you're doing when you set a new key in a python dict like `dct['count'] = some_value` (note this is not a perfect comparison as you cannot call python dict keys as attributes directly, but the concept is similar).

This goes a bit into object oriented programming, which you should look into if you're still confused. If you're still having trouble with your code above, I believe simply dropping the `inplace` portion would solve the problem as pandas would handle the operation and create whatever attribute is needed before setting the reference to your new frame.

```
group_index = group_index.rename(columns={'index':'name','first_name_ini':'count'})
```

Comment: thank you, I know more about the difference between these two expressions, and as @AdibP said, it was just because the column name conflicted with [panda.DataFrame.count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html)